# Keep selected values in multiple nested dropdown after return to view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, model-view-controller

I have view with 2 nested dropdown lists that filters data from database and show filtered result in a table. 
In that table, i have an link to another view that shows details for selected database record.

Is it possible (and how) to keep selected values of master view dropdowns after user click on a "back" button in browser when viewing details view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should use viewstate
dont use session it is heavy weight object so take more loading on server

Comment: Can't use ViewState if the user is leaving the page and coming back to it.

Comment: who say cant use viewsate

Comment: ViewState goes out to the page and back.  How would you use ViewState if you're moving across pages?

Answer (score 0):

Why not put it in a Session

```
Request.Session["Value1"] = "Your value"
```